# StringBuilder() vs StringBuilder(null) vs StringBuilder("")

Tags: java, null, stringbuilder

public class TestMyStringBuilderII {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Hello");
    StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder("World");
    StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();
    //StringBuilder sb3 = new StringBuilder(null);
    StringBuilder sb4 = new StringBuilder("");

    System.out.println(sb);
    System.out.println(sb.length());
    System.out.println(sb.append(sb1));
    System.out.println(sb.append(sb2));
    //System.out.println(sb.append(sb3));
}
```

}

The sb3 = new StringBuilder(null) results in NullPointerException. Now, what is the difference between StringBuilder(), StringBuilder(""), and StringBuilder(null)?

a) System.out.println(sb2); is printing empty space when the actual characters ("null") was expected to be appended (according to the AbstaractStringClass definition) - why?

b) System.out.println(sb2.length()); is printing 0, so is this because sb is not really "null" (meaning it is some thing/type with length of zero?)

c) System.out.println(sb4); is printing empty space and System.out.println(sb4.length()); is printing 0 (assuming clearly that sb4 is actually of String because of the double quotes used for the argument, but with zero length) - correct?

Not sure if this question is formulated correctly, but I would appreciate if someone who can understand my thinking/confusion here and clarify these a bit.

Comment: Perfect, all four answers below make sense. Thanks all

Answer (score 4):

`new StringBuilder("abc")` is a convenience overload for `new StringBuilder().append("abc")` except that javadoc says:

> The initial capacity of the string builder is 16 **plus the length of the string argument**.

This is intended to create a larger initial backing array, for improved performance, though that is likely minuscule.

Since you cannot take the length of a null value, you get `NullPointerException`.

Comment: +1, additionally the source code helps to reveal those mysteries http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/StringBuilder.java

Answer (score 2):

`new StringBuilder()` and `new StringBuilder("")` are equivalent; they both create an empty `StringBuilder`, with no contents, not a `StringBuilder` containing `null` in any sense.  I believe this answers all three of your questions.

Answer (score 2):

StringBuilder() and StringBuilder("") are doing quite the same.

While StringBuilder() only calls super(16) where it initializes a char array with a length of 16, StringBuilder("") adds the length of "" to 16 and then calls super, which looks like this: super(str.length() + 16).
So both return you an initialized StringBuilder object.

StringBuilder(null) crashes because of super(null.length() + 16)

Answer (score 0):

- a) `System.out.println(sb2);` prints nothing (not even an empty space) because `StringBuilder` is empty.
- b) prints zero because `StringBuilder` is empty (length of contained String is 0).
- c) prints nothing because nothing was appended.